# pure virtual class c++

Tags: c++, class, virtual, abstract

I've got a problem when trying to create a sub class from an abstract class

```
class people 
{
public: 
   people();
   ~people();
   virtual int comparable(people*); 
   void order(people**,int);
};
```

my subclass

```
class worker : public people
{
private: 
  int salary;
public: 
  worker();
  ~worker(); 
  int comparable (people*);
};
```

I need to order a dynamic array of people by salary (from worker) but i can't match a people array[j]=worker a;

What so you suggest?
and then how do i call de function order? because a can't create a people object

Comment: You want to sort `people` by `salary` but not `people` doesn't have a `salary`, so how do you plan on doing this? Do you want `salary` to be part of the `people` class? Do you want to have a dynamic list of `workers` instead?

Comment: Explain what array[j]=worker a; is supposed to mean or do. This isn't even valid syntax.

Comment: You have the right idea. Implement `comparable` in `worker` where you can use salary.

Comment: There's no _pure virtual_ declarations in the classes you mention? Did you mean `virtual int comparable(people*) = 0;`?

Answer (score 1):

Provide a pure virtual function to compare two `people`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

class people 
{
   public: 
      people();
      ~people();
      virtual int compare(const people* rhs) const = 0; 
};
```

Implement the `compare` function in `worker`.

```
class worker : public people
{
   private: 
      int salary;
   public: 
      worker();
      ~worker(); 
      virtual int compare(const people* rhs) const
      {
         const worker* rhsw = dynamic_cast<const worker*>(rhs);
         if ( NULL == rhsw )
         {
            throw std::invalid_argument("rhs");
         }
         return (this->salary - rhsw->salary);
      }
};
```

Provide a functor that you can use in `std::sort`.

```
struct people_compare
{
   bool operator()(people* lhs, people* rhs) const
   {
      return (lhs->compare(rhs) < 0);
   }
};
```

Use `std::sort` and the above functor to sort the list of people.

```
void order(people** plist, int num)
{
   std::sort(plist, plist+num, people_compare());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a rather strange thing to do, and it would make more sense to have a `salary` variable in `people` if you are expected to sort some sort of collection of `people` by their salary.

It's also not clear to me what the return value from `comparable` is, but here's a solution that sorts based on `salary`, and assumes that a `people` object that isn't of `worker` type (or derived thereof) has zero salary. It returns 0 for equal salary, 1 for "this object has greater salary than the passed in object" and -1 for "less salary than passed in object".

Note however that this is a pretty bad design, you shouldn't, typically, use `dyanamic_cast` like this.

```
int worker::comparable(people *p)
{
   worker *w = dynamic_cast<worker*>(p); 
   int wsalary = 0;
   if (w) 
      wsalary = w->salary;
   if (salary == wsalary) return 0;
   if (salary > wsalary) return 1;
   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to order a dynamic array of people by salary (from worker) but [...]. What do you suggest? and then how do I call the function `order`?

I'd consider refactoring your code. For a dynamic array I would use an `std::vector` and for ordering you can use `std::sort`.

If you want a decoupled system you should probably move the "container and sorting specific code" away from the `person` and `worker` class.

In fact it turns out that you don't even need a base class or public inheritance at all in this case. You can define a compare function for every class of your hierarchy. In particular for `worker`:

```
bool compare(const worker &a, const worker &b) {
    // return true if a is < b
    // example follows
    return a.salary < b.salary;
}
```

And finally, you are left with:

```
class worker {
    // ...
};

std::vector<worker> workers;
```

and when you need to sort the `workers` vector you can simply do:

```
std::sort(workers.begin(), workers.end(), compare);
```

---

If it makes sense to be able to do `worker_a < worker_b` (even though discrimination based on the salary is not exactly a popular opinion) you could implement an `operator<`:

```
struct worker {
    bool operator<(const worker& rhs) {
        // for example
        return salary < rhs.salary
    }
};
```

and just sort with:

```
std::sort(workers.begin(), workers.end());
```